# Select css tags with randomized letters at the end

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently learning web scraping with python. I'm reading *Web scraping with Python by Ryan Mitchell*.

I am stuck at *Crawling Sites Through Search*. For example, [reuters search](https://www.reuters.com/search/news?blob=hello) given in the book works perfectly but when I try to find it by myself, as I will do in the future, I get this [link](https://www.reuters.com/site-search/?query=hello).

Whilst in the second link it is working for a human, I cannot figure out how to scrape it due to weird class names like this `class="media-story-card__body__3tRWy"`

The first link gives me simple names, like this `class="search-result-content"` that I can scrape.

I've encountered the same problem on other sites too. How would I go about scraping it or finding a link with normal names in the future?

Here's my code example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from rich.pretty import pprint

text = "hello"

url = f"https://www.reuters.com/site-search/?query={text}"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

results = soup.select("div.media-story-card__body__3tRWy")

for result in results:
    pprint(result)
    pprint("###############")
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 2):

You might resort to a prefix attribute value selector, like

```
div[class^="media-story-card__body__"]
```

This assumes that the class is the only one ( or at least notationally the first ). However, the idea can be extended to checking for a substring.

Comment: I've tried that and it does not work. `results = soup.select('div[class_="media-story-card__body__"]')` or results = soup.select('div[class_*="media"]') don't show anything. Maybe I'm doing it wrong but that's how I understand it.

Comment: @KapJ1coH drop the underscore from your selector (`class*=` instead of `class_*=`)